# Linq-to-xml group by elements that don't have child elements

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-xml

I was wondering if anyone can help with the following:

I've got a xml document like this:

```
<div class="_cl">element description 1</div>
<div class="_cl">
    <anotherele>dtls</anotherele>
    <anotherele>moredtls</anotherele>
</div>
<div class="_cl">
    <anotherele>dtls</anotherele>
    <anotherele>moredtls</anotherele>
</div>
<div class="_cl">element description 2</div>
<div class="_cl">
    <anotherele>dtls</anotherele>
    <anotherele>moredtls</anotherele>
</div>
<div class="_cl">
    <anotherele>dtls</anotherele>
    <anotherele>moredtls</anotherele>
</div>
```

I was wondering if there was any way in linq to group this by elements that don't have child elements. Basically, trying to structure the document somehow like this:

```
<div class="_cl">element description 1
   <div class="_cl">
       <anotherele>dtls</anotherele>
       <anotherele>moredtls</anotherele>
   </div>
   <div class="_cl">
       <anotherele>dtls</anotherele>
       <anotherele>moredtls</anotherele>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="_cl">element description 2
   <div class="_cl">
       <anotherele>dtls</anotherele>
       <anotherele>moredtls</anotherele>
   </div>
   <div class="_cl">
       <anotherele>dtls</anotherele>
       <anotherele>moredtls</anotherele>
   </div>
</div>
```

My first woeful attempt looks like this:

```
var n = from a in doc.Descendants()
                where a.Name.LocalName == "div" && (string)a.Attribute("class") == "_cl"
                group a by a.Value.Length<50 into g 
                select new { k = g.Key, p = g.Count() };
```

Hope this makes sense and thanks in advance.

Stu

Comment: I don't really understand what are you trying to do... You can't group by a condition - you can group by fields... No child elements is a condition, you can filter by it, but not group.

Comment: If what you're saying is true then it wouldn't be possible then. Do you have any other solution to shape the xml?

Comment: What I'm saying, is that your request is not logical... please explain more correctly what are you trying to do.
A sample output could be nice.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example, assuming the input is

```
<body>
<div class="_cl">element description 1</div>
<div class="_cl">
  <anotherele>dtls</anotherele>
  <anotherele>moredtls</anotherele>
</div>
<div class="_cl">
  <anotherele>dtls</anotherele>
  <anotherele>moredtls</anotherele>
</div>
<div class="_cl">element description 2</div>
<div class="_cl">
  <anotherele>dtls</anotherele>
  <anotherele>moredtls</anotherele>
</div>
<div class="_cl">
  <anotherele>dtls</anotherele>
  <anotherele>moredtls</anotherele>
</div>
</body>
```

then the code

```
    XDocument input = XDocument.Load("input.xml");

    XDocument output = new XDocument(
        new XElement(input.Root.Name,
            from el in input.Root.Elements()
            where el.Elements().Any()
            group el by el.NodesBeforeSelf().OfType<XElement>().LastOrDefault(e => !e.Elements().Any()) into g
            select new XElement(g.Key.Name,
                g.Key.Attributes(),
                g.Key.Nodes(),
                g)
            ));

    output.Save(Console.Out);
```

outputs

```
<body>
  <div class="_cl">element description 1<div class="_cl"><anotherele>dtls</anoth
erele><anotherele>moredtls</anotherele></div><div class="_cl"><anotherele>dtls</anotherele><anotherele>moredtls</anotherele></div></div>
  <div class="_cl">element description 2<div class="_cl"><anotherele>dtls</anoth
erele><anotherele>moredtls</anotherele></div><div class="_cl"><anotherele>dtls</anotherele><anotherele>moredtls</anotherele></div></div>
</body>
```

This is what you want I think, with the exception of the indentation. As for the indentation, you might get closer to your desired result by loading the input with `XDocument.Load("input.xml", LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace)`.

For more on this grouping approach, see http://msmvps.com/blogs/martin_honnen/archive/2009/11/27/grouping-with-linq-to-xml.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

Svarog is right; what you're trying to do can't be achieved by grouping. You'd need some more advanced Linq expressions than are given in the Linq keywords.

Try this:

```
var n = doc.Elements().Where(div=>!div.Elements().Any()).
        Select(div=>{
            div.Add(
                div.ElementsAfterSelf().TakeWhile(x=>x.Elements().Any())
            ); 
            return div;
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your input, but none of the solutions seem to quite cut it. I think what I'll do is just loop through the elements and parse it manually. I just thought a nice linq one-liner would be better.

Cheers

Stu